# Application Insight not logging exception details

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get the exception details from Application insight every time I get a 5xx status code back but I cannot find it. As you can see in the message it only says "Request failed".
Below a screenshot

[image]

Comment: How did you instrument your code. How did you log errors? `ILogger`? Do you use a custom `ExceptionHandler`(Middleware)? ...

Comment: What is the .NET version you are using?

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs`, `appsettings.json` and `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to log `Exception details` with the full message.

Check the below code configuration.

***My `appsettings.json` :***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=*****;IngestionEndpoint=https://**.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

Add the below lines of code in ***`Program.cs`*** file.

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

***My `HomeController.cs` :***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Controller Information");
            _logger.LogDebug("Debug message in Index");
            _logger.LogWarning("Warning Message");
            _logger.LogError("Error message in Index");
            return View();

        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {          
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return View();
        }      
    }
}
```

***Exception Message :***

[image]

- We can see the clear `Message` and `Exception type`.

[image]

- Also, we can see the exact message with line of code in the Call Stack.

[image]