# Application Insights not logging unhandled Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-application-insights

I am working on a .net 6 web API.

I have installed the package

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
```

The configuration is as below. I have not included the reset of the configuration for security reasons.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      },
      "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey"
    }
  }
}
```

Telemetry extension is as follows

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;

namespace MyApplication;

public static class ApplicationServicesLoggingExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds production loggers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddLogging(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return services.AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddEventLog(config => { config.SourceName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName; });
                logging.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddApplicationInsights(
                    config =>
                    {
                        config.ConnectionString =
                            configuration.GetSection("Logging:ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString").Value;
                    },
                    options => { options.FlushOnDispose = true; });
                logging.AddDebug();
            })
            .SetupStorageFolderForTelemetryChannel(configuration);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Setup up telemetry with a storage folder using <see cref="ServerTelemetryChannel" />
    ///     and installs a custom initializer that helps identify the application generating telemetry
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IServiceCollection SetupStorageFolderForTelemetryChannel(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetryInitializer>();
        var configuredStorageFolder = configuration.GetValue<string>("ApplicationInsights:StorageFolder");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuredStorageFolder))
            return services
                .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        var baseFolder = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
        var storageFolder = Path.Combine(baseFolder, configuredStorageFolder);

        var f = new DirectoryInfo(storageFolder);
        if (!f.Exists) f.Create();
        // This sets up ServerTelemetryChannel with StorageFolder set to a custom location.
        return services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITelemetryChannel),
                new ServerTelemetryChannel { StorageFolder = storageFolder })
            .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }
}
```

and the custom telemetry initializer is as below

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace MyApplication;

public class CustomTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomTelemetryInitializer(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        SetApplicationNameToRoleName(telemetry);
        SetEnvironmentNameToRoleInstanceAddingDate(telemetry);
        SetAMachine(telemetry);
    }

    private void SetApplicationNameToRoleName(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["MachineName"] = Environment.MachineName;
    }

    private void SetAMachine(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var appName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ApplicationName");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appName)) return;
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = appName;
    }

    private void SetEnvironmentNameToRoleInstanceAddingDate(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var environmentName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Environment");
        var dc = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:WarehouseNumber");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dc)) return;
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = $"{environmentName}-{dc}";
    }
}
```

and finally registering it on the main program as below

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(builder.Configuration);
```

I am expecting the unhandled exceptions to be logged in the Application Insights. I have and orchestrator API where it calls multiple APIs in order to complete a transaction. When one of the APIs is taking too long time it is throwing exception. This exception is not getting logged in the insights. How do I make sure that all the unhandled exceptions are logged in the application insights?

Note: I am able to see the Trace logs in the application when I set the loglevel to Information.

Update:
After an update I am now able to see the logs upto the occurence of timeout exception. But not the logs related to exception itself. Earlier in program.cs the AddControllers was called after AddSwaggerGen. Now I moved it before the AddSwaggerGen like in below.

```
builder.Services
    .AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration)
    .AddLocalAutoMapper(builder.Configuration)
    .AddAuthenticationJwtRsa(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("WmsSecurity:IdentityProviderVerificationKey"))
    .AddOptions()
    .AddSfcProdLogging(builder.Configuration)
    .Configure<AppSettingsOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services
    .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        //swagger config
    });
```

The timeout exception is still not logged.

Comment: Could you please share your Configuration file.

Comment: Where does your `ApplicationServicesLoggingExtensions` and `custom telemetry  initializer` resides

Comment: Add the connection string from the configuration file in `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry`

Comment: Refer this SO Threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416314/application-insights-not-showing-all-errors/76437244#76437244) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784136/application-insight-not-logging-exception-details/75789384#75789384) which logs the exceptions.

Comment: In the API, add the try and catch blocks to handle exceptions.

Comment: Here I have removed the connection string for security purpose

Comment: Have you deployed your app to azure ?