# Application Insights is not logging if an exception is passed to LogError (or other Log* methods), but does log if the exception is NOT passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET 8 web API hosted in Azure App Service.

I encountered an issue where I'd get a 500 response due to an error with my DB logic, but there were no entries in the exception log in the App Insights section of the portal.

I added a few test logging lines to my controller code to explicitly catch the exception and try manually logging, and found that nothing was logged if I passed an exception as the first argument to the Log* methods. If I don't pass the exception, and just pass a message, it DOES log.

I'm using the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package on the latest version (2.22.0).

My config:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my Startup file I'm calling `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`

My controller code to test this out is:

```cs
try
{
    var updatedCase = await ...; // DB update logic that may throw ConcurrencyException

    return Ok(...);
}
catch (ConcurrencyException cEx)
{
    logger.LogError(cEx, "DEBUG ERROR: CAUGHT CONCURRENCY EXCEPTION"); // NOT logged
    logger.LogInformation(cEx, "DEBUG INFO: CAUGHT CONCURRENCY EXCEPTION"); // NOT logged
    logger.LogInformation("DEBUG INFO: CAUGHT CONCURRENCY EXCEPTION (NO EX)"); // LOGGED under traces in App Insights
    throw; // The rethrown exception is NOT logged
}
```

I'm not sure if it helps but the custom `ConcurrencyException` looks like this - Do I need to be doing something else with this to make it loggable?:

```cs
public class ConcurrencyException : Exception
{
    public ConcurrencyException() { }

    public ConcurrencyException(string message)
        : base(message) { }

    public ConcurrencyException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner) { }
}
```

And the library code that throws it looks like this:

```cs
catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict || ex.Headers["x-ms-substatus"] == "409" || ex.SubStatusCode == 409)
{
    throw new ConcurrencyException($"Concurrency conflict when appending to stream {streamId}. Expected revision {firstEventNumber - 1}", ex);
}
```

If I don't catch/handle the exceptions, I get a 500 response, but nothing is logged in AppInsights.

Weirdly, if I catch the `ConcurrencyException` and attempt to log it, it does not appear in AppInsights. If I catch it and throw a new Exception, then that new exception DOES get logged, e.g.

```cs
try
{
    ...
}
catch (ConcurrencyException cEx)
{
    ...
    throw new Exception("DEBUG: A NEW EXCEPTION"); // Note that if I do this, then it DOES get logged!
}
```

How can I get App Insights to log these exceptions?

Comment: Arre you seeing that exception in transaction search?

Comment: @Harshitha no, they aren't there in the transaction search.

Comment: Refer this similar [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784136/application-insight-not-logging-exception-details) once.

Comment: @Harshitha I've checked my config, and I have the relevant line in Startup. If I manually throw a new Exception it gets logged. It seems that it's something to do with the custom exception.

Comment: Are you sure your custom exception is raised? Can you check that in local?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I tried catching it to check if it was raised, and the catch block is hit. If allowed to propagate up it never gets logged. If manually logged using LogError(ex, "msg") it never gets logged. If manually logged with a new exception, LogError(new Exception("gets logged"), "msg") then it DOES get logged. I'm quite confused as to why the custom exception isn't logged properly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257132/discussion-between-harshitha-and-neil-mountford).

Comment: Are you still having the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to log Error as an Exception with and without passing EX.

```cs
 catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict || ex.Headers["x-ms-substatus"] == "409" || ex.SubStatusCode == 409)
 {
   _logger.LogError("DEBUG: A NEW EXCEPTION without Ex");
   _logger.LogError(ex, "DEBUG ERROR: Error EXCEPTION with ex");
   _logger.LogInformation(ex, "DEBUG INFO: Information EXCEPTION with ex"); 
   _logger.LogInformation("DEBUG INFO: CAUGHT CONCURRENCY EXCEPTION (NO EX)"); 
 }
```

- In Transaction Search you can only see the EX messages.

[image]

- Click on the `Exception` => `End-to-end` transaction details

You can see the Exception with Severity Level.

***Error with EX:***

[image]

***Information with EX:***
[image]

- Also set the LogLevel as shown below.

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
   ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
```

***`appsettings.json`***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
       "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=****;IngestionEndpoint=https://****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"

  }
}
```